# Leaflet 1 beta 2 not working with mapbox-gl.js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Leaflet v1.0.0-beta.2 not working with 
mapbox-gl.js  (I have tried v15 and prior versions)

Or does it work with a specific version of mapbox-gl.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand this question. mapbox-gl.js does not work with leaflet in any way. Are you asking about mapbox.js?

Comment: Your answer actually solved my question. I guess what I need is this: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet.   thanks!